# How to change formik <Field/> component's placeholder?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

Basically I'm not able to make date input empty with Formik. I just want it to show nothing initially. This is what I've been dealing for hours.

```
 <Field
 name="date"
 type="date"
   className={`InformationForm__field text-[20px] lg:h-14 px-4 lg:py-4 py-3  outline- none 
                                           `}
                                            />
```

note: I've tried placeholder, giving empty string as initial value etc.

Anyone have idea?

Answer (score 1):

Yo can try below code

```
     <Field
       name="date"
       render={({ field, form: { isSubmitting } }) => (
           <input {...field} type="date" 
            placeholder="date" />
       )}
     />
```

Check this link for more info:- https://formik.org/docs/api/field#render

Comment: how exactly is this a date input?

Comment: Just need to change the type of input

Answer (score 0):

Searching on docs I've found this prop `initialValues`, try that one.

[Reference](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#initialvalues-values)

Comment: if you leave empty string or undefined or something like that, it's printing dd.mm.yyyy

Comment: Maybe it's a lib design choice, I think it makes sense to show to user what type of input he should use.